# Need help with zend form validation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I wanted to create an invitation form for user to signup. But the signup form is only for people have the special invitation code. So how can I set it in Zend form validation to check if the invitation code matches the code the user enter. The invitation code is the same for all the people that are invited.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
                    $invitationElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('invitationCode');
                    $invitationElement->setLabel('Invitation Code');
                    $invitationElement->setRequired(true);
```

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use 5.3 you can use the callback validator with an closure:

```
$valid = new Zend_Validate_Callback(function($value){
    // some validation
    return true;
});
```

or you could use the regex validator

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^Test/');
```

or the Identical validator:

```
$valid = new Zend_Validate_Identical('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the controller (fetch the POST data and check whether it matches your invitation code - and if not, add an error t othe form element), or you can write your own custom validator. [This post](http://cogo.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/custom-validators-for-zend_form_element/) might help you with the custom validator writing (or just google for further resources).

Answer (score 0):

This is business requirement and you should validate it inside the business layer and I suggest you the same.

I would suggest you to have a unique query-string that identifies the request and process the page. Something like

> http://www.example.com/signup?invite=som32mthing23unique0988h

Make sure people have the above code when you display the form.